# Tools for Operating on Large Amounts of Text Data

Tags: python, big-data

I need to handle and process  ~5 million news articles, an amount small enough to fit on a commodity desktop but too large to process serially.  Thus far, I have been using Python/`pickle` for serialization, but this is easily getting out of hand.  However, I do not have a server much less a cluster immediately available for distributed storage.

What tools can I use to store, query, and operate on this size of a dataset?  The majority of operations I need to do can be formulated as Map operations; the only exception is that the Natural Language Processing portion which is handled by calling Stanford's CoreNLP software suite (it needs a few seconds to load some large parameter files).

Comment: Your doing this with _Python_?

Answer (score 1):

Many people speak highly of [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It specializes in searching large quantities of text, and should be usable from Python.

I suppose you could also do something custom with [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). It directly supports map reduce operations, though it might be easier to work in Java than Python with Hadoop.

Comment: Solr is good... :)